# Conditional Expectation involving Uniform Random Variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

$X,Y \stackrel{i.i.d}{\sim} U[0,1]$. I am supposed to find $E[X|X>Y]$.

My approach was:

Let $X>Y$ be denoted as event $A$ for the time being.

$f(A)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}1 dydx = 0.5$

Now, $E(X|A) = \frac{\int_{0}^{1} x f (X\cap A)}{f(A)} dx$  =  $\frac{2}{3}$

How do I Approach this problem using the Indicator function?

Comment: The proposed duplicate concerns $E(X \mid X \lt Y)$ and the most upvoted Answer shows how to use an indicator function $\mathbf 1_A$.  The only point I would add about your approach is that you only defined $f(A)$, not $f(X\cap A)$, so the meaning of the latter is unclear.  Making that meaning precise is naturally done using an indicator function, as the Answer posted below makes clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You... basically did so.$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X\mid X>Y)&=\dfrac{\mathsf E(X\,\mathbf 1_{X>Y})}{\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_{X>Y})}\\[1ex] &=\dfrac{\displaystyle\iint_{[0,1]^2} x\,\mathbf 1_{x>y}\, \mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x}{\displaystyle\iint_{[0,1]^2}\mathbf 1_{x>y}\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x}\\[1ex] &=\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_0^x x\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x}{\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_0^x \,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{1^3/3}{1^2/2}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{2}{3}\end{align}$$

Comment: thanks for the answer!